# I cannot install Blazorise in my Blazor server side app. I get the Error that "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor" package could not be find

Tags: razor, blazor, blazor-server-side, nuget-package, blazorise

I have a blazor server side app that is working without problem. (Net Core 3.1). I tried to install Blazorise according the quick start page in https://blazorise.com/docs/start. As my server has no internet access I have downloaded the packages "Blazorise.Bootstrap 0.7.2" and "Blazorise.Icons.FontAwesome 0.9.2.5".

I can install the "Blazorise.Icons.FontAwesome" without Error. But if I try to install "Blazorise.Bootstrap" I get the Error

"NU1101: Unable to find package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor. No packages exist with this id in source(s): Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages, Package source"

I cannot find any package like "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor". What should I do now?

Update1:
I have found a package like "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Templates 3.1.0-preview4.19579.2" but if I try to install I get Error

"Package 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Templates 3.1.0-preview4.19579.2' has a package type 'Template' that is not supported by project 'WebApplication7'"

Comment: Those packages are super old school and out of date. The newer Blazorise stuff all targets .NET 6/7 because the older stuff is EOL. That being said, if you really want to continue down this path you may have to build the package from [the source](https://github.com/aspnet/blazor/tree/5deb85df8784800742e7a6d68575c67dd6fedb5a) yourself.

Comment: Agree with @Lex. Both Blazor and Blazorise are seeing frequent updates. More important than ever to stay current.  .Net Core 3.1 support ends 12/13/22.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had some problmes at the beginning with updateing NetCore3.1 to Net6.0 But at the end I fixed them. So I could install Blazorise's last version without problem.
Thanks for the comments, suggesting that.